# SQL Multiple foreign keys ON DELETE causing an #1215 error

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I got one table that holds some data and has two foreign keys.
One key that references a parent table and another that references a user table.

#### This code fails throws an #1215 error (code is Laravel):

I **want** the respondent_id to be **set null** when the parent is deleted, this is a requirement.

```
// answer forgein key
$table->integer('answer_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('answer_id')->references('id')->on('answers')->onDelete('cascade');

// Respondent forgein key
$table->integer('respondent_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('respondent_id')->references('id')->on('respondents')->onDelete('set null');
```

#### While this one works:

```
// answer forgein key
$table->integer('answer_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('answer_id')->references('id')->on('answers')->onDelete('cascade');

// Respondent forgein key
$table->integer('respondent_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('respondent_id')->references('id')->on('respondents');
```

#### Notes:

1. Tables are both **innoDB**
2. Both columns are the **same datatype**

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Seems like i answered my own post.

While writing this answer i had a thought: **"Can the field even be null?"**. Then i said to my self ofcource not, Its not nullable!

After changing the code to the below; it worked perfectly.

```
// answer forgein key
$table->integer('answer_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('answer_id')->references('id')->on('answers')->onDelete('cascade');

// Respondent forgein key
$table->integer('respondent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('respondent_id')->references('id')->on('respondents')->onDelete('set null');
```